# opacity based on scroll left distance

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, opacity

```
$(document).scroll(function() {

    var distanceLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();

    if( distanceLeft > 3800)
    {
        $('#first_circle').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000);
    }

    if( distanceLeft < 3800)
    {
        $('#first_circle').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000);
    }
)};
```

Hi
Im trying to correct this so that when the scroll goes past 3800 the div fades in and when the user scrolls back it fades out?
thank you for any input

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: it doesnt animate to 0 when scroll < 3800

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: its basically this http://jsfiddle.net/z7E9u/1/ but I want the element to fade from 0 to 1 opacity between 3575 and 4150 scroll left distance but the maths is interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the vars and add some math: http://jsfiddle.net/z7E9u/155/

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use a simple way like [mkey answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917074/1250044). However if you need a more complex thing to *"animate"* try [jQuery Transe](https://github.com/yckart/jquery.transe.js). It is a *thorough* solution for exactly this problem. You can change almost anything based on the current scroll offset (even CSS3-Transforms and suchlike).

In your case, try something like this:

```
$('#fading').transe({
    direction: 'x',
    start: 3575,
    end: 4150,
    css: 'opacity',
    from: 0,
    to: 1
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TvSyU/)**